# Aquaris M10 FHD Ubuntu Edition

Tags: camera, framerate

Does it has enough hard to be able to record in more than 30FPS, will the camera have the possibility to be set for this?

I plan to use it for sport training purposes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

iam assuming ur using ip camera@30FPS , depending on resolution ,and frames per second,  for 3 MP camera (2048*1536) pixel, It should be possible if u r using one camera, it will be 15360 to 8192 kbps . the higher bit rate the higher picture quality u get, At 8192 is 8 Mbps which is still alot and good enough, Note that most of nvr are limitted to 16Mbps. u may want to record on a NAS drive directly from the camera, and that's what iam trying to figure out so far.
NOW if its enough hard drive, that's its not a question because the hard drive is ur choice and has no thing to do with ubuntu edition or whatever FHD u mentioned.
In this case if ur using 4 TB hard disk u should get record arround 20 days for one camera

Comment: what? I'am talking about the new tablet from bq.com